# Getting SQL query values

Tags: sqlite

I'm not very good at SQL queries. That's why I'm asking this question.
Here is a simple table I have created in sqlite.

For example I want to get "Location" names between Lattitude 8.1 to 8.5 && Longitude 80.4 to 81.5

How can I write a query to get those values? Please can someone write the query for me.

Thank you for your time......

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT Location
FROM tablename
WHERE Latitude BETWEEN 8.1 AND 8.5
AND Longitude BETWEEN 80.4 AND 81.5
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with:

```
SELECT *
  FROM your_table
 WHERE Latitude BETWEEN 8.1 AND 8.5
   AND Longitude BETWEEN 80.4 AND 81.5
```